# Multiple Chrome instances with Selenium: "Closing stream with result -2" Error in Instance 1 when running driver.close/quit in Instance 2

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running a combination of BeautifulSoup and Selenium for the following scenario:

1. Open Webdriver (Chrome) with Selenium, waiting for commands.
2. Infinite loop of BeautifulSoup in the background to check website for changes every few seconds
3. If a certain change is detected, use Selenium to open/load website and click a few buttons to render content I want to scrape.

I am tracking changes on two different websites. I could just test the two websites in the same script, but I need to track the changes as soon as possible. Therefore, I'm also opening Selenium at the beginning of the scripts to save time before changes are detected so that I don't have to wait for Chrome to first boot up as soon as a change is detected.

I need the cookies of my Chrome default profile to access the website (Two-factor login), so I copied my User Data folder to load two sessions of Chrome. If I don't do that, I get an error in the second instance, saying that the profile is being in use, can't edit the files yada yada...

Opening one instance/list/website is fine, my script runs without any issues.
When I open a second instance of the script, checking a different website in a new window of Chrome, the first script gives me the following error whenever the second script initiates driver.close() or driver.quit().

```
[22384:16640:0909/170836.278:ERROR:socket_stream.cc(219)] Closing stream with result -2
```

This doesn't shut down my first script, it seems to keep working fine. So I'm not even thinking this has any detrimental impact on what I am trying to do, but I wonder what is happening here and why are the two instances seemingly interacting with each other when they shouldn't really?

I'm using two different copies of chromedriver.exe for each script as well, not even sure if that is necessary.

Anyway, would appreciate if someone could enlighten me about what is going on.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you won't need to use two different chromedrivers... does the error also happen when the 2nd browser instance closes?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
ERROR:socket_stream.cc(219)] Closing stream with result -2
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was an error while invoking `CloseStream()`.

This error is coming from [`void SocketInputStream::CloseStream()`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/google_apis/gcm/base/socket_stream.cc#198) function defined in **`socket_stream.cc`** which is defined as:

```
void SocketInputStream::CloseStream(net::Error error,
                    const base::Closure& callback) {
  DCHECK_LT(error, net::ERR_IO_PENDING);
  ResetInternal();
  last_error_ = error;
  LOG(ERROR) << "Closing stream with result " << error;
  if (!callback.is_null())
    callback.Run();
}
```